# HighCharts, HighStock, assign javascript array to data, new to me

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What's the easiest way to get my data to show in HighCharts/HighStock? I'm populating the javascript arrays from another source, but I don't know how to assign my javascript array data to the series.  I've looked at other examples and posts, but I just don't get it. Any helpful pointers or links to tutorials would be appreciated.

```
arClosingDates[0] = '2/1/2013'
arClosingDates[1] = '2/2/2013'
arClosingDates[2] = '2/3/2013'
arClosingDates[3] = '2/4/2013'
arClosingDates[4] = '2/5/2013'

arClosingPrices[0] = 3.23
arClosingPrices[1] = 3.28
arClosingPrices[2] = 3.56
arClosingPrices[3] = 3.90
arClosingPrices[4] = 3.23


    $('#Chart1').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Test Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Test',
            data : [arClosingDates[],arClosingPrices[]],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are formatting the data array incorrectly. Try this instead:

```
var arClosingData = [
        [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1), 3.23],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 2), 3.28],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 3), 3.56],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 4), 3.90],
        [Date.UTC(2013, 1, 5), 3.23]
    ];
```

...

```
series: [{
            name: 'Test',
            data: arClosingData,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
```

[jsFiddle example using your data](http://jsfiddle.net/5RBVj/)

EDIT: I forgot that the month parameter in DATE.UTC(year, month, day)  expected 0-11 instead of 1-12.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It looks like I need to decrement the month by one to get the right UTC date.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I forgot about that.  I edited the answer to make it complete.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually pretty tricky to get the details down. I had to iterate through my arrays and create an array of arrays.  Then my dates were in the wrong format, so I had to change them to the UTC date, then I struggled with my numbers which were actually string numbers, so I learned about parseFloat and more.  So I definitely appreciate the help!